# Printing product variation return array to string conversion error

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to echo product variation data using Woocommerce plugin.

I have the following code that suppose to parse array using `foreach` loop:

```
$variableProduct = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

$allVariations = $variableProduct->get_available_variations();
foreach ($allVariations as $key => $value) 
{ 
    echo $value;
}
```

But instead I'm receiving

> Notice: Array to string conversion

How to print product variations correctly?

EDIT:

The array receives inside has multiple arrays:

> Array ( [attributes] => Array ( [attribute_%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%93%d7%94]
> => [attribute_%d7%a6%d7%91%d7%a2] => ) [availability_html] => [backorders_allowed] => [dimensions] => Array ( [length] => [width] =>
> [height] => ) [dimensions_html] => N/A [display_price] => 99
> [display_regular_price] => 100 [image] => Array ( [title] =>
> sample-slide-1 [caption] => [url] =>
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1.jpg
> [alt] => [src] =>
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-600x270.jpg
> [srcset] =>
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-600x270.jpg
> 600w,
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-300x135.jpg
> 300w,
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-1024x461.jpg
> 1024w,
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-768x346.jpg
> 768w,
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-1600x720.jpg
> 1600w,
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-1536x691.jpg
> 1536w,
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-150x68.jpg
> 150w,
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1.jpg
> 2000w [sizes] => (max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px [full_src] =>
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1.jpg
> [full_src_w] => 2000 [full_src_h] => 900 [gallery_thumbnail_src] =>
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-100x100.jpg
> [gallery_thumbnail_src_w] => 100 [gallery_thumbnail_src_h] => 100
> [thumb_src] =>
> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sample-slide-1-300x300.jpg
> [thumb_src_w] => 300 [thumb_src_h] => 300 [src_w] => 600 [src_h] =>
> 270 ) [image_id] => 210 [is_downloadable] => [is_in_stock] => 1
> [is_purchasable] => 1 [is_sold_individually] => no [is_virtual] =>
> [max_qty] => [min_qty] => 1 [price_html] => [sku] =>
> [variation_description] => [variation_id] => 309 [variation_is_active]
> => 1 [variation_is_visible] => 1 [weight] => [weight_html] => N/A )

Comment: Well , You Are echo array Not possible , echo is used print string you can use print_r($value); function for print array.

Comment: @HK89 But I used foreach to extract that array values

Comment: @HK89 You are correct, but now I got multiple arrays for each variation that I don't know how to handle. got any reference for me to read?

Comment: What's get in this array

Comment: @HK89 edited my question

Comment: What data do you need?

Comment: @HK89 I've inserted to each product variation color and size, I want to extract each variation.

Comment: I already give answer in this Url [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/376992/fetch-product-information-in-woocommerce/377024#377024]